# From query send email in Access

Tags: database, email, ms-access, vba

I am making a system for my school with a database that sends an email to the resources department every time a worksheet needs to be printed out.

The table's fields are:

- ID (an auto number)
- The web address of the online file (a hyperlink)
- The key (what the user types in to the parameter query that then emails the corresponding data to resources (a text string)
- A description of the worksheet (a memo)

To send the email, the user fills in a set of parameter query. Instead of the query results coming up, the email should be sent. The query should contain the following fields:

- The key of the worksheet (a text string)
- How many worksheets need to be printed (a number)
- Any notes (a memo)
  Then they click OK and the email is sent.

The email should contain this information, which corresponds to the data entered in the query:

- A hyperlink to the worksheet
- How many worksheets the user said need to be printed
- The notes the user submitted and the notes already in the table

To download my database so far, [click here](http://1drv.ms/1S6BObS).

I would like to do this in VBA code. Could you guide me along the right lines to making this work? Any code suggestions would be helpful as I am new to VBA.
Thanks

Comment: Well our department have a limited budget so if we have to spend any money we will have to cancel the project or choose an alternative

Comment: @HansUp I can get a query to work, I just don't know if the way I do it is right for this project

Answer (score 0):

First, add "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library" to your references (you might have a different number than 14.0) by click on "Tools" then "References". I have the following code that does a bit more than you're asking but it will work. The signature argument is the text body as string. When creating the string, use "vbCrLf" to create new lines, e.g. signature = "Hello, how are you?" + vbCrLf + "I am fine." will put the sentences on two separate lines.

```
Private Sub createEmail(ByVal toEmailAddresses As String, _
                    ByVal ccEmailAddresses As String, _
                    ByVal att1 As String, _
                    ByVal att2 As String, _
                    ByVal signature As String, _
                    ByVal subject As String, _
                    ByVal displayIt As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo foundError
    Dim outItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outItem = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    outItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    outItem.Recipients.Add toEmailAddresses
    outItem.cc = ccEmailAddresses
    outItem.subject = subject
    If att1 <> "" Then
        outItem.Attachments.Add (att1)
    End If
    If att2 <> "" Then
        outItem.Attachments.Add (att2)
    End If

    outItem.HTMLBody = signature

    outItem.Send
    'Note: if you wanted to create the email and check it first, use outItem.Save
    Exit Sub
foundError:
    MsgBox "Error in createEmail: " + CStr(Err) + ", " + Error(Err), vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I have to edit my database query/table/forms for this to work?

Comment: No. You should be able to copy it into your module (you might need to make it a Public Sub) and just pass the arguments.  Oh you can remove the "displayIt" argument, in my version I can opt to display the email. But you do need to add the reference to the MS Outlook Object Library.